# My custom page have HTTP header 404 not found

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

I have created two custom pages and integrated it into Drupal 7.

There are on follow links:

http://will.sx/404
http://will.sx/billing

I have issue with HTTP headers. I need it for implement one of functionality. All above two links have a HTTP header 404 Not Found.

I prove it to myself using:

```
$header = drupal_get_http_header("status");
print_r($header);
```

on the /404 page and in a left upper corner I got message '404 Not Found'

I'm so confused and don't know why this happen.

The way on which I created these custom pages is creating a custom .tpl.php files for example:
page--404.tpl.php etc.

How is possible to get 404 Not Found although page content is rendered as you can saw if you already visited links that I write above.

Any kind of help is welcome. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

drupal_get_http_header() should be treated as deprecated.

All HTTP information is being centralized on the Request/Response objects.

Please refer this issue : https://drupal.org/node/1969270

Comment: In Drupal 8 I see this is basically deprecated. But why in Drupal 7 has this stopped working?

Comment: Found my problem was when using Masquerade drupal_get_http_header() does not return accurate results. So the function still works properly in Drupal 7.